# iomanip errors or ‘setw’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, ubuntu, iomanip

In this function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern const int M;

void outnum(int* &arr)
{
    for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
        cout << setw(4) << arr[i];

    cout << endl;
}
```

I get an error

```
error: ‘setw’ was not declared in this scope
   cout << setw(4) << arr[i];
                 ^
```

When I try to include iomanip, during the compilation there appear a lot of lines like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
```

Is it something special for Ubuntu?

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

extern const int M=5;
extern const int N=4;

int **makemas(int m, int n);
void output(int** &array, int m, int n);
int *number(int** &array, int n, int m);
void outnum(int* &arr);

int main()
{
int **a, **b;
int *anum, *bnum;

...

cout<<"  Number of minus elements in A:"<<endl;
outnum(anum);
cout<<"  Number of minus elements in B:"<<endl;
outnum(bnum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the error singles out `std::setw`, it's a good idea to find a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) on it.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with ubuntu, but I actually doubt it. [Here it compiles fine.](http://ideone.com/yp8Jee)

Answer (score 14):

You need to add `#include <iomanip>` in order to use `std::setw()`. If you are getting errors on that, then something else is going on, either Ubuntu's STL is messed up, or something else is interfering with the compile.